# has_many :through create duplicates in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, duplicates, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many-through

I created 3 models, User, City, UserCity.

User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_cities, :dependent => :destroy, :uniq => true
  has_many :cities, :through => :user_cities
end
```

City class:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_cities, :dependent => :destroy, :uniq => true
  has_many :users, :through => :user_cities
end
```

UserCity class:

```
class UserCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
end
```

And then I tried

```
u = User.new()
c = City.new()
u.cities << c
c.users << u
p UserCity.all.size # => 2
```

user_cities table had duplicates. So then, I coded

UserCity class:

```
class UserCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :city_id}
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
end
```

and run the same ruby code above. But it failed after `c.users << u` because I prohibited duplicate.

How can I make `u.cities` have `c` and `c.users` have `u` without duplicating data in join table?

---

Added:

So, if I choose only `c.users << u`, can I only do this for `cities`?

```
cities = Array.new()
UserCity.where(:user_id => u.id).each do |uc|
  cities << City.find(uc.city_id)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose either `u.cities << c` or `c.users << u`. Each of them cause a row inserted in to the join table.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Must I choose one? I want to display "Cities which the user visited" and "Users who visited the city"

Comment: Yes, choose only one. then you can associate the relevant rows from both way (from both user and city), Active Record will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to prevent duplicates in the db by adding an index in the db which would raise an error if you accidentally try to add a duplicate join entry.  Do something like this in a migration:

```
add_index :cities_users, [:city_id, :user_id], unique: true
```